# Upgrading mongodb not working because dpkg was interrupted?

Tags: apt, upgrade, dpkg, mongodb

I'm trying to upgrade from mongodb 3.2.10 to 3.4.4. This is on a c9.io environment that I use for developing, and the upgrade seemed to work on the production server.

It seems to have taken the list upgrade, but when trying to download and apply the upgrade, it eventually gives the the same error.

```
user:~/workspace (master) $ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
Ign:1 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.4 InRelease
Hit:2 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.4 Release
Hit:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security InRelease               
Ign:5 http://us-central1.gce.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty InRelease         
Hit:6 http://us-central1.gce.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates InRelease
Hit:7 http://us-central1.gce.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-backports InRelease
Hit:8 http://us-central1.gce.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty Release
Reading package lists... Done 
WARNING: Running upgrade on your Cloud 9 instance will use your disk quota for package upgrades.
Each time a new workspace is created it is using very recent packages already, try just installing
the packages you require first.

Press Y to continue anyway
y
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
```

I've run `sudo dpkg --configure -a` (many times) and it refreshed the server, but will still give me that same error next time I try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try  to remove all the files inside /var/lib/dpkg/updates directory ,

```
cd /var/lib/dpkg/updates
sudo rm *
```

And then run

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: worked like a charm, surprised I didn't see this in any of the other threads I looked at!